# this item is not compatible with your device SAMSUNG Advance

Tags: android, google-play, manifest

I distribute Android app to Google Play Store.

I received "this item is not compatible with your device samsung advance" from my user.

Phone is Samsung Advance.

Manifest:

```
<permission        
        android:name="pl.w.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"        
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="pl.w.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use     
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS" />

    <uses-feature        
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"       
        android:required="true"/>
```

In App settings content rating is Low Maturity.

Answer (score 0):

Some features you added in the Manifest file is not available in your device.

Your device does not support the feature you requested in the manifest file.

Try removing the unwanted permissions given in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with one of my application. Even Samsung Galaxy Star advance is not listed in the supported devices in developer console. All the other applications are being installed properly except for my application and the problem is only with this device (Samsung Galaxy Star Advance).

Comment: There was one internal library which our company used which was not supporting lower versions of Android. That was the issue.